# Center align hidden divs within <li> tags for menu dropdown

Tags: css

I have a horizontal menu based on [this](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/how-to-build-a-kick-butt-css3-mega-drop-down-menu/) that is pure CSS and HTML and am trying to center align the dropdown divs under each top level menu item but am having some difficulty getting it to work. It currently aligns to the right, and any changes I make when changing to "relative" positioning of the child elements correct alignment of the parent/child but then throw off the top level items because the children take up the space between items.

Below is the code for an item, followed by the associated CSS.

Html:

```
<ul id="menu">

    <li><a href="#" class="drop">Home</a>
        <div class="dropdown_2columns">

            <div class="col_1">
      <p class="black_box">Download stuff here<br><img src="img/menu-button.png"></a></p>

            </div>    
            <div class="col_1">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Item 1</li>
                    <li><a href="#">Item 2</li>
                    <li><a href="#">Item 3</li>
                </ul>   

            </div>

        </div>
    </li>
```

CSS

```
    #menu {
    text-align:center;
    color: #2262a0;
    list-style:none;
    width:690px;
    margin:30px auto 0px auto;
    height:28px;
    padding:0px 20px 10px 20px;
        background: #fff;

}
   #menu li {
    float:left;
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
    position:relative;
    padding: 4px 10px 4px 10px;
    margin-right:0px;
    margin-top:7px;
    border:none;
}

#menu li:hover {
    padding: 4px 9px 4px 9px;*/
}


.dropdown_1column, 
.dropdown_2columns, 
.dropdown_3columns, 
 {
    background:url("img/blue-arrow.png") no-repeat center 0px z-index;
    margin:10px auto;
    float:left;
    display: inline-block;
    position:absolute;
    left:-999em; /* Hides the drop down */
    text-align:center;
    padding:10px 5px 10px 5px;
    border-left:1px solid #e5edf4;
    border-right:1px solid #e5edf4;
    border-top:3px solid #004b91;
    border-bottom:3px solid #e5edf4;
}

.dropdown_1column {width: 260px;}
.dropdown_2columns {width: 520px;}
.dropdown_3columns {width: 780px;}

#menu li:hover .dropdown_1column, 
#menu li:hover .dropdown_2columns, 
#menu li:hover .dropdown_3columns,
{
    left:-1px;
    top:auto;
}

.col_1,
.col_2,
.col_3,
 {
    display:inline;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
.col_1 {width:250px;}
.col_2 {width:500px;}
.col_3 {width:750px;}
```

Any CSS guru's out there care to send some advise?

Answer (score 0):

In the example posted you can move the boxes by changing

```
#menu li:hover .dropdown_1column, #menu li:hover .dropdown_2columns, #menu li:hover .dropdown_3columns, #menu li:hover .dropdown_4columns, #menu li:hover .dropdown_5columns 
{
      left: -212px; /*for column 4*/
}
```

Of course you would have to have a static width for each box and style them accordingly.

Comment: Super helpful! Thanks twodayslate!